# PageViewer loads blank view...getItem() not being called

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, layout-inflater

I am attempting to use viewpager to create a horizontal scrolling layouts.  The app runs without errors but when the activitymain layout is set and the adapter for the viewpager is set, the app only displays a blank screen.  After doing some debugging using Log.d() I have found that the getItem() method in my adapter class is not being called which I suspect is the problem.

I am clueless how to fix this, please take a look at my code below and help if you can, thank you all.

```
Main Activity Code:

package myapp.pkg;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    ViewPager viewpager = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("Debug","content set");

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mainpager);

        FragmentManager fgm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        viewpager.setAdapter(new VPAdapt(fgm));
        Log.d("Debug","adapt set");

    }
}
```

Page Viewer Adapter

```
package myapp.pkg;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

class VPAdapt extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {
        public VPAdapt (FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
            Log.d("Debug","VPAdapt called");
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int i)
        {
            Log.d("Debug","VPAdapt getItem called i = " + i);

            Fragment frag = null;

            if(i == 0)
            {
                frag = new HomeT();
                Log.d("Debug","HomeT set");
            }
            if(i == 1)
            {
                frag = new NewsT();
                Log.d("Debug","HomeN set");
            }
            if(i == 2)
            {
                frag = new FeatT();
                Log.d("Debug","HomeF set");
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

One of the Fragment classes

```
package myapp.pkg;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class HomeT extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup vg, Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {

        return inf.inflate(R.layout.hometitle, vg, false);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
@Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

It loads blank because the number of fragments you specify is 0.

**solution:**

return the number for fragments in the ViewPagers's `getCount` instead of 0

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
   return 3;
}
```

Comment: No that is not it, the getItem() method is not dependent on getCount(), and if I change the return number to anything higher than 0 that causes a nullPointerException

Comment: @user3167555 huh?? what you mean. getCount is the number of fragment in the ViewPager 0 means you there is nothing in there.

Comment: @user3167555 change this `return null;` to `return frag;` and make sure that getCount `returns 3`

Comment: aahh i see, ok thank you very much, i did not think that getItem() was dependent on getCount(), my app works now, thank you